# Upload Image in the wrong directory in django ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-2.2, django-uploads

When I upload a photo, the photo is loaded successfully, ***but the photo is placed in the wrong directory.***

Instead of placing the image on the path to `'media/posts-pics/'` - as I have outlined in my Post model - it is placed on the `'media'` path.

These are my files:

> ## models.py

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    index_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts-pics/')
```

> ## Project.urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> ## views.py

```
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.index_pic = form.cleaned_data['index_pic']
            new_post.save()

            return redirect('view_post')

    else:
        form = AddPostForm()
    template = 'post/add_edit_post.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)


def edit_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            Post.objects.filter(id=post.id).update(title=request.POST['title'],
                                                   index_pic=form.cleaned_data['index_pic'],
                                                   )

            return redirect('view_post')
    else:

        form = AddPostForm(instance=post)
    template = 'post/add_edit_post.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

I used exactly the same code for `add_post`, and the photo was in its place, but I got into trouble in `edit_post`. ***what's wrong ?***

Notice:

> Technically I can delete `'media/post-pics'` but this is done with a
>   special purpose and the purpose is: Each app have its folder for
>   saving images.

Comment: You can remove the redundant parenthesis like this: `index_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts-pics/')`

Comment: I deleted the parentheses but the problem did not resolve.@Stevy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're no using your `ModelForm` the right way.

In the edit_post view, you want to replace this:

```
Post.objects.filter(id=post.id).update(
    title=request.POST['title'],                                                   
    index_pic=form.cleaned_data['index_pic'],
    )
```

with a plain simple:

```
 form.save()
```

which will take care of the updating the post passed as `form.instance` (using sanitized data, which is not the case with your current code)

FWIW, in your add_post view, you also want to replace this

```
        new_post = form.save(commit=False)
        new_post.index_pic = form.cleaned_data['index_pic']
        new_post.save()
```

with a plain simple:

```
        new_post = form.save()
```

Once again, the whole point of ModelForms is that they know how to create and update model instances.

Comment: I had a special situation, which is why I used update method. Some data will not get from user.
 As a result, it does not create a field in `request.POST` and then in `AddPostForm` to give it the desired values. 
 What do I need to do? A simple example for these fields are `created_date` and `modified_date` (of course, there are other fields like these, which the user should not fill but is filled by the system).@bruno-desthuilliers

Comment: I've included your suggested code in my application. Another problem I encountered in addition to the above comment is:
When I save, the values of the fields I mentioned are replaced with empty values. @bruno-desthuilliers

Comment: I explain my 2 above comments in this [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451143/why-executing-form-is-valid-cause-deleting-of-the-instance-fields-that-arent) @bruno-desthuilliers . Plz check that.

Comment: This is nothing of a "special" situation, really, and Django offers ways to deal with this by making some fields non-editable at the model level (typically creation and last modification dates etc) and by excluding some fields from ModelForms. All of this is documented (in the models and forms parts of the fine manual).