# Why executing form.is_valid() cause deleting of the instance fields that aren't in the form in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-2.2

Suppose this view that is for edit record:

```
def edit_post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        # 1
        if form.is_valid():
            # 2
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.save() 
            return redirect('administrator:view_admin_post')
    ...
```

*Now assume these:*

1. I have `field1` that is exist in `POST` model.
2. `field1` has default value and suppose that the current value of
   `field1` depends on previous.
3. Also suppose that I don't want to pass the `field1` to user. As a
   result, I will not have it in `request.POST`.

In this situation when I write `print(post.field1)` In line `# 1` I have previous value but when I print that in 
line `# 2` I got `None`!

What is going on?And how can I have my `post.field1`?

*Notice:* I know I can define a middleware variable and save the previous value in this variable.**But is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: If you don't want a field to be overwritten by the form, you need to exclude it from the form's fields list.

Comment: Does your solution include what I want to show the fields in my template but do not want to overwrite it?@DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point: `.is_valid()` will NOT touch your database (unless you customize the form's validation, but then, well, you'd know why xD). It's the call to `Model.save()` (either directly or thru `form.save()`) that overwrites the previous value.

Second point: if you pass a model instance to your form (which is what you do), you can access it (and it's fields) thru `{{ form.instance.your_field_name }}` in the template.

And finally, you can either totally exclude a model field from the ModelForm, or mark it as read-only.

All of this is rather well documented FWIW, so I kindly suggest you take some time reading the doc before going any further with bizarre and convoluted "solutions" (hint: you definitly don't need a middleware to get the original value, it's still in your database - until you overwrite it, that is).

Comment: Please introduce some doc for this problems @bruno-desthuilliers

Comment: I think that when form.is_valid() execute, the fields of post change to `None`. You can test that by doing what I did @bruno-desthuilliers

Comment: I think that you did not understand me precisely. I know that if I pass and edit my form I can exclude some field but if i exclude some field I can't show them in the template. Or if I set some field to `non-ediable` how can  I show them in the template? @bruno-desthuilliers

Comment: "I think that when form.is_valid() execute, the fields of post change to None" => no they don't, and I don't need any test to tell you so - just read the code (or trace it in the step debugger) and you'll find out by yourself.

Comment: "i exclude some field I can't show them in the template" => nope but you can display the value from the `post` instance itself _as explained in my answer_. Or you can make the fields read-only (which is not the same as excluding them) but this is insecure as it will only impact the HTML form itself (how the browser will render the HTML field), but not prevent someone from actually posting a new value in the HTTP request.

Comment: "Please introduce some doc for this problems" => for non-editable model fields look at the "models" chapter, for excluding fields from a ModelForm look at the "model forms" part of the "forms" chapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot plz vote my question if you want @bruno-desthuilliers

Comment: This is my last question: if >Can I tag you for future questions I have new question ? @bruno-desthuilliers